# Instagram: Get photos from a tag after a specified photo

Tags: instagram

I'm working on an instagram scraper for something and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get all photos for a tag that have an id or timestamp later than the last one I have.

The instagram API docs are useless in that they don't have any real info on pagination (which I presume I'll have to abuse).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you check http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/? That page contains some useful information on pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I've been slogging through the Instagram API for the last couple of days so here's my 2 cents worth:
As far as I can see it if you call the api with /tags/tag-name/media/recent it only return a list if items. If the amount exceeds about 25 you have to make another request with the pagination value returned in the previous request.

In order to gain some control I am initially iterating through all images and storing the results (just the URL not the actual image) to a database. Now I can manipulate however I want. When I feel like updating (I'm doing it manually now but could be a cron job or use the [real-time api](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)) I re-read all the images, compare to what I have in my DB and add possible new images. My app then reads out the url and info from my DB (which btw is a heck of a lot faster than going through the instagram api, which will only return about 25 images per request - regardless of any 'count' parameter value you put in the request url) and displays it.

I am developing this for a client who is afraid of people posting nsfw or whatever pics using their dedicated hashtag (for a contest) - with the above set up I can offer them an interface where they can check and mark images that are then displayed in the app.

One thing to watch out for is when a user deletes his picture; you will have to find a way to check for this. Currently (since I'm lazy) I load all images and use jquery to check for an error loading the image. If there is one I delete the image from the DB (via ajax).

I'm not sure the pagination is going to help you: as far as I can see the pagination response has no relation to the id's of the actual image objects on each page - so theoretically a pagination id that jumps to a certain page (i.e. date) might not work tomorrow if enough images have been deleted in the mean time.

Comment: Cheers John. As it happens, we did pretty much the exact same thing when I built the system last year. One thing that you may find handy (which took me way to long to find out), is that the you want the oembed link, not the amazon s3 link for the images or they expire.

Comment: Duh, just realized this was an old question... sry ;)
That's a great tip, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get all images instead of latest 20, just append &count=-1 to your api call - it's that simple.
In either case, there is a timestamp on each json object - or if you prefer, you can use  max_tag_id

check out my post here: [there any way to show more than 20 photos of the instagram API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521081/there-any-way-to-show-more-than-20-photos-of-the-instagram-api/12531284#12531284)

*** Update April 2014**: `count=-1` is no longer available.