# there any way to show more than 20 photos of the instagram API?

Tags: instagram

I'm trying to display more than 20 photos feed in a website like this:

http://snap20.com.br/instagram/

There's any way to show?

Comment: if you accept answers, people will be more willing to help you out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram has a 20 image limit on their API, check out this thread and my answer:

[What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram)

Also, have a look at this link to bypass the pagination and display all results:

http://thegregthompson.com/displaying-instagram-images-ignoring-page-pagination/

Comment: Hmm, I was able to get more using the count= option and client_id= option.

Comment: The greg thompson link is no longer working.  If you find it, please update information here as EVERYONE seems to reference that link, but no one summarizes its content.

Comment: Also of note, if you are sandboxed, no number in a count parameter will allow you to get more than the first 20 images.  Pagination does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Simple. Just append `&count=-1` at the back of your api call.
For instance:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOURTAG/media/recent?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN&count=-1
```

*** Update April 2014** (credits: @user1406691): `count=-1` is no longer available. Response:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APIInvalidParametersError","code":400,
"error_message":"Count must be larger than zero."}}
```

You may wish to use this instead:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/YOURTAG/media/recent?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN&count=35
```

There's also another method via rss + db but it's longer, although it's not limited to 30 calls / hour.

Comment: on April 2014 count=-1 is been disabled

Comment: I don't know since when but now even if you put `count` value in api call it returns you maximum 33 results. I think better to implement pagination to next set of result.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a chance to get the next 20 pictures, and after that the next 20 and so on...
In the JSON responce there is an "**pagination**" array:

```
 "pagination":{
      "next_max_tag_id":"1411892342253728",
      "deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
      "next_max_id":"1411892342253728",
      "next_min_id":"1414849145899763",
      "min_tag_id":"1414849145899763",
      "next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/lemonbarclub\/media\/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\u0026max_tag_id=1411892342253728"
 }
```

this is the information on specific API call and the object "**next_url**" shows the URL to get the next 20 pictures so just take that URL and call it for the next 20 pictures...

for more information about Instagram API check this out: https://medium.com/@KevinMcAlear/getting-friendly-with-instagrams-api-abe3b929bc52